# Composer Installation problem - Error: Add to System path: C/xampp/php

Tags: xampp, composer-php

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LSUm.png)

I'm installing Composer for for a Laravel project for school and I'm encountering this error installing with with xampp php.

This may sound stupid for many of you, but please bear with me, I'm still new to this and our school learning system isn't really great.

Anyways, I tried putting the whole xampp folder into the Program Files folder of my PC to try and remedy this error (I got confused before and instead installed a separate php instead of the one from xampp. Almost got it finished by doing this since I also encountered the same error because I installed php outside of my Program Files folder but I stopped after one of my classmates noticed that I was getting all of it wrong) and of course it didn't work.

Comment: What is "this error"? Please share the error message in text form, along with your attempts to resolve the error